TypeError in Recoil state while testing with React testing library
This below code in my Recoil state model throws an error during testing with React Testing Library
import { atom } from "recoil"

export const BooksState = atom<BooksModel[]>({
  key : "BooksDataState",
  default: Array<BooksModel>()
});

The error says

TypeError: (0 , recoil_1.atom) is not a function

